# Pandas iterate two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

i have two df, in one i have the list of several ids and in the other the name of the person and the id.

I want to loop them that when the id in df1 equals the id df2, he takes the name in df2 and create in df1.

I tried to adapt this code with wuzzy that I found, but didn't create.

```
for key,row in df.iterrows():
    choices = str(list(df2.NAME_ID.unique()))
    names = process.extract(str(row['P1_ID']), choices, limit=2)[0][0]
    name = df2[df2['NAME_ID'] == names]['NAME']
    if not name.empty:
        df.loc[key,'Name'] = name





import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')  

GAME_DATE_EST   GAME_ID GAME_STATUS_TEXT    P1_ID   P2_ID   SEASON  P1_ID   PTS_P1
0   2020-01-01  21900504    Final   1610612764  1610612753  2019    1610612764  10
1   2020-01-01  21900505    Final   1610612752  1610612757  2019    1610612752  9
2   2020-01-01  21900506    Final   1610612749  1610612750  2019    1610612749  10
3   2020-01-01  21900507    Final   1610612747  1610612756  2019    1610612747  8
4   2019-12-31  21900497    Final   1610612766  1610612738  2019    1610612766  9
```

df2

```
     NAME_ID    STANDINGSDATE NAME      G   W   L   W_PCT
0   1610612747  2020-01-01    Math      34  27  7   0.79
1   1610612743  2020-01-01    John      33  23  10  0.70
2   1610612746  2020-01-01    Elias     35  24  11  0.69
3   1610612745  2020-01-01    Alexander 34  23  11  0.68
4   1610612742  2020-01-01    Michael   33  21  12  0.64
```

I hope you understand and can help me

Answer (score 1):

For that, you can do a simple [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
newdf = df.join(df2, on='NAME_ID', how='left')
```

Based on your given data, you can try:

```
df.merge(df2[['NAME_ID','NAME']], left_on=['P1_ID'], right_on=['NAME_ID'], how='left')
```

Comment: doesn't work, both df have multiple columns and ids repeat over and over

Comment: could you please provide a sample data for me to check

Comment: are from matches, the first df brings the matches (game date, winner id, loser id, points, etc ..) the second df brings player performance (name, id, victories, losses, etc), i want to bring the name of the player in second df to the first based on id in all matches.

Comment: Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: I edited the post, (I don't know how to use the pd.read_clipboard)

Comment: I could not use this code, it restarts my notebook, and use all ram in google colab. hahaha